# Не могу получить данные из input с помощью js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу получить значение input c id "dir"
Что делаю не так?
В консоли выводятся все переменные за исключением DIR
DIR undefined и всё тут ((

```js
$(".save").click(function() {
  var A = $(this).parent().parent();
  var X = A.attr("id");
  var d = X.split("formbox"); // Определяем id : formbox
  var id = d[1];
  var Z = $("#" + X + " input.name").val();
  var S = $("#" + X + " input.am").val();
  var DIR = $("#" + X + " input.dir").val();
  var Y = $("input[name=noind]:checked").val(); //Получаем значения с radio чекбоксов
  var I = $("input[name=tp]:checked").val(); //Получаем значения с radio чекбоксов
  var D = $("input[name=del]:checked").val(); //Получаем значения с radio чекбоксов
  console.log("var S " + S);
  console.log("var Z " + Z);
  console.log("var Y " + Y);
  console.log("var I " + I);
  console.log("var D " + D);
  console.log("var DIR " + DIR);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" name="form332">
  <input id="name332" data-lpignore="true" type="text" value="Название продукта" name="name">
  <input type="text" value="0" name="am" class="am">
  <input id="index332" type="radio" name="noind" value="0" checked="checked">
  <input id="noindex332" type="radio" name="noind" value="1">
  <input id="photo332" type="radio" name="tp" value="0" checked="checked">
  <input id="price332" type="radio" name="tp" value="1">

  <input id="dir332" type="hidden" value="product-1" name="dir">

  <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="alt_edit">
  <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="save">
</form>
```

Comment: где у вас инпут с классом `dir` ?

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало! Я думал тут завязано name=, а оказывается по классу )) Я только учусь ))